# Wordpress next/previous set of posts not working with my theme

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, pagination

I have an issue with the next/previous (next_posts_link) within Wordpress. This function adds a link at the bottom of a list of posts to allow a user to view the next set of posts, or the previous. Simple pagination is usually output.

I am using the Reverie theme and this includes it's own custom code for this:

```
<?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
<?php if ( function_exists('reverie_pagination') ) { reverie_pagination(); } else if ( is_paged() ) { ?>
<nav id="post-nav">
    <div class="post-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'reverie' ) ); ?></div>
    <div class="post-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'reverie' ) ); ?></div>
</nav>
<?php } ?>
```

I have also tried the standard wordpress code:

`<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>`

Both of these generate the links, and takes the user to /page/2/ - however the same set of posts appears on the second page as on the 1st. I limit the first page to say, 3 posts, so there should be different links on the second page.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

adding paged to your posts query

```
        $query_recents = new WP_Query ( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

worked for me

Comment: Not sure where in my snippet to add that query?
@andi-wilkinson
`<?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
<?php if ( function_exists('reverie_pagination') ) { reverie_pagination(); } else if ( is_paged() ) { ?>
<nav id="post-nav">
 <div class="post-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'reverie' ) ); ?></div>
 <div class="post-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'reverie' ) ); ?></div>
</nav>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: are you using a plugin? Im not a code expert, so i can't pick it apart, hopefully you have been able to find an answer, i know i came across the same issue and i literally just added 'paged' => $paged into my existing query

Comment: Not yet @andi-wilkinson I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
    elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
    else { $paged = 1; }

    query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged); 
    ?>
```

Try using this if it can solve. This code worked for me. Then use navigation link code.